# How to prove an exponential function preserve the positive semi-definite property?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

If $f(x) \in \Re$ has the positive definite property, $\sum_i\sum_j a_i a_j f(x) \geq 0$ for $a_i,a_j \in \Re$, then $e^{f(x)}$ has the positive definite property.

How can i prove it?

And, i guess a composition function $g(f(x))$ has the positive definite property, if $g(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function.
Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to show that:

$$e^{f(x)} = 1 + f(x) + \frac{(f(x))^2}{2!} + \frac{(f(x))^3}{3!} + ... $$

Now the properties of PSD functions is that, if $f_i(x),i\in \mathbb{R}$ is PSD then, $af_i(x)$ [given $a\geq 0$], $(f_i(x))^d$ [given $d\geq 0$ and integer], $f_i(x)+c$ [given $c\geq 0$] and $f_i(x)+f_j(x)$ are PSD functions.

Combining all that, $e^{f(x)}$ is PSD function.